# Запросить с tg-бота jpeg файл из другого модуля

Tags: python, aiogram

Задача стоит такая: пользователь по запросу из tg-бота получает изображение, которое генерится в программе обработки изображения. И бот, и программа обработки написаны на python.
Программа обработки выглядит следующим образом: в цикле крутиться обработка потокового видео

```
while True:
if cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES) == cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT):
    cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, 0)

success, img = cap.read()
imgGray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
imgBlur = cv2.GaussianBlur(imgGray, (3, 3), 1)
imgThreshold = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(imgBlur, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C,
                                     cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV, 25, 16)
imgMedian = cv2.medianBlur(imgThreshold, 5)
kernel = np.ones((3, 3), np.uint8)
imgDilate = cv2.dilate(imgMedian, kernel, iterations=1)

checkParkingSpace(imgDilate)

cv2.imshow("Image", img)
# cv2.imshow("ImageBlur", imgBlur)
# cv2.imshow("ImageThres", imgMedian)
if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
    break
```

Обдумал вариант создания restful сервера на django, чтобы связать модули.
Суть вопроса: стоит ли создавать api для связывания двух программ или это можно сделать иным способом?

Comment: В сторону `threading`  смотрели?

Comment: Связать меж с тобой два куска кода на пайтоне на одном жестком диске?

Comment: @gord1402, буду задавать до жути дилетантские (может детские) вопросы: для чего использовать многопоточность в данном случае? Я бы хотел развернуть бота и программу (видимо сервер - на примере на django). Делать запросы с бота на сервер. Но вот как перехватывать работу интерпретатора с цикла while для выполнения кода (в моем случае создания скриншота)? Именно для этого и использовать многопоточность?

Comment: @СергейШ, я бы хотел развернуть бота и программу (видимо сервер - на примере на django). Делать запросы с бота на сервер. Но вот как перехватывать работу интерпретатора с цикла while для выполнения кода (в моем случае создания скриншота)? Именно для этого и использовать многопоточность?

Comment: @mr.Haze1nut  потоковое  видео нужно только для бота или используется для чего-то ещё? Если только для бота, то почему бы не получать изображение только тогда, когда приходит запрос на сервер? Можно ли поместить код бота к коду обработчика чтобы не отправлять изображение через сеть?

Comment: @gord1402, результаты работы обработки видео нужны в непрерывно в реальном времени, поэтому по-простому было решено зациклить работу программы. Лайф данные также должны выводиться в отдельном модуле на дисплей. Но как сделать работу программы без остановки (кроме while true), к стыду, не знаю. 
И 2 вопрос: можно поместить всё одну кучу, но я пытался "проектировать" архитектуру под потенциальное расширение (т.е. написать api для мультипоинт доступа). Знаете ли Вы способы склейки этого всего?

Comment: @mr.Haze1nut тогда поместите цикл в функцию и редактируйте в нём глобальную переменную после запустите функцию с помощью `threading` в другом потоке и используйте глобальную переменную где хотите.

Comment: глобаль ная переменная в aiogram плохая идея